# DOMPDF outputs bad html on Linux

Tags: php, html, dompdf

UPDATE1:
Works pretty well on Ubuntu but not on CentOS.

I have a issue with the DOMPDF on CentOS Linux VPS,

I output an HTML with css on my WAMPP and works pretty well:

[image]
But when i upload the same code, the same html it shows as this:

[image]

I tried everything like check encoding, inline css, enabling remote but still no way to get this running, here is my code:

```
                    require_once(APP . 'vendors' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS . 'dompdf_config.inc.php'); 
                spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload'); 
                $dompdf = new Dompdf();
                def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);
                $_GET['print'] = 1;
                $dompdf->set_paper("A4", "portrait");
                $this->output = '';
                $this->layout = 'none';
                $old_output = $this->output;
                $this->render('innobra_pdf');
                $new_output = $this->output;
                $dompdf->load_html($new_output);
                // $dompdf->load_html( utf8_decode($new_output), Configure::read('App.encoding') );
                $dompdf->render();
                $output = $dompdf->output();
                header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                echo $output; die();
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you copying your entire project from one server to another (including dompdf)? Is the directory structure the same on both? If your external resources are pulled from the web (i.e. include a domain in the reference) does the non-working server have `allow_url_fopen` set to true?

Comment: @BrianS Even with allow url fopen doesnt work

Comment: @BrianS i have the tmp folder chmodded to 777 all files have the same structure

Comment: FYI, remote resources in dompdf up to and including 0.7.0 require the PHP setting `allow_url_fopen` to be true. You're using the `load_html()` method, and so any relative path references may be incorrect. Have a sample of the HTML dompdf is attempting to render?

Comment: Here is the sample: 
    http://pastebin.com/8HmehEUM

Comment: It looks like the resources referenced via the web (anything with a protocol + domain, e.g. http://innobra.bimsapp.com/img/custom/innobra.png) aren't being pulled in. Two possible causes I can think of right away: no read/write access to the dompdf temp directory; `allow_url_fopen` is false.

Comment: @BrianS take a look of this:
http://pastebin.com/Q3R0m9E4

Comment: I see a closing comment delimeter without an opener in your stylesheet (.contract h1), maybe it's causing problems. The real issue seems to be that the files could be corrupt. Did you upload from one server to another? Try installing a fresh copy on the server having problems. But it also looks like file_get_contents is returning some bad data. You might want to see what it looks like. Try setting `debugKeepTemp` (v0.7.x) or `DEBUGKEEPTEMP` (v0.6.x) to true and looking at the files.

Answer (score 2):

If you have copied to another server, try deleting the file

```
dompdf/lib/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache.php
```